# Allocate space back to Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning

As you can see from this image:
[image: Disk partition structure]

I have 3.90GB of unallocated space (Reference "A"), and 107.68Gb of "unused" space on my Microsoft Windows partition (Reference "B")...

I would like to allocate both of these back to Ubuntu's respective partitions.

Specifically, I want all of the unallocated space made available to Ubuntu, and as much as possible with regards to the Windows partition (I only keep Windows around "just in case", until I upgrade my laptop next year, when I'll go single-boot Ubuntu).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be a little bit of work...

Step 0:  Back up your data

Step 1:  First, you will need to shrink the Windows partition (ref. B) - this should be done from inside Windows, while Windows is running.  You can use Windows disk management tools to do this.

Step 2: Secondly, you will need a liveUSB of Ubuntu to change the Ubuntu partitions, as these partitions cannot be modified while they are being accessed by Ubuntu.  Because of the way your disk is arranged, this will be a two step process, at least.

Step 2a)  Incorporate the free space into the extended partition /dev/sda4:  Booting from the LiveUSB, run the program `gparted` and use this program to add the extra space into /dev/sda4.  You may need to move partition /dev/sda3, depending upon how Windows handles shrinking that partition.

Step 2b)  Using `gparted`, add the unused space now in /dev/sda4 to your Ubuntu partition, /dev/sda5.  Again you may need to move partitions on the disk to have the unused space contiguous to /dev/sda5

Comment: That unallocated space - Reference "A" - is all I was able to obtain from Microsoft Windows using the disk management tools... It would not allow me to "shrink" the volume by any more.

Does that mean the unallocated space is all I'm going to get back from the Windows partition (Reference "B")?

If so, I might just look at a "clean", single-boot installation of Ubuntu...

Comment: I would not try to force MS to give up any more space, although it would be great if Windows would play nice.  The problem is that there is something out on that disk MS does not want to move, and if you move it with gparted, MS won't be able to find it, and your Windows install may not boot.  I run my copies of Windows in a VM now, for those few programs that I can't live without.

Comment: Ugh, "clean" install it is then... It's easy, but a pain-in-the-butt because of the time taken to complete the process.

You technically answered my question though, so thanks!

Comment: @GregoryOpera  Sorry, but I can't say the I have not had to do the same thing myself a time or few!